# Javascript voting acts_as_votable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app, in which my Posts model has Comments and the comments are votable. I'm using acts_as_votable.

I currently have the voting on the comments working. Now I'm trying to implement some javascript so that the page does not have to refresh every time someone votes on a comment, so that the vote goes through.

Here is what I had before(which was working):

In my comments controller:

```
  def upvote_post_comment
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.liked_by current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
  end
end
```

And in my view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user != comment.user && !(current_user.voted_for? comment) %>


<%= link_to image_tag(‘vote.png'), like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put %> <a>
<%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>


<% elsif user_signed_in? && (current_user = comment.user) %>

<%= image_tag(‘voted.png')%><a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>

<% else %>

<%= image_tag(‘voted.png')%><a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>
<% end %>
```

And this is what I now have:

In my comments controller:

```
 def upvote_post_comment
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
 @comment.liked_by current_user

respond_to do |format|
format.html {redirect_to :back }
format.json { render json: { count: @comment.liked_count } }
end
end
```

And in my view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user != comment.user && !(current_user.voted_for? comment) %>


    <%= link_to image_tag(‘vote.png'), like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, class: 'vote', remote: true %> 
<a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>


  <script>

    $('.vote')
  .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
  .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
  .on('ajax:success', function (data) { $(this).html(data.count); });

    </script>


  <% elsif user_signed_in? && (current_user = comment.user) %>

  <%= image_tag(‘voted.png')%><a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>


  <% else %>

  <%= image_tag(‘voted.png')%><a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a>


    <% end %>
```

This shows me the error message: "There was an issue"

And when I refresh the page, I see that the vote went through and I see this in my terminal:

```
Started PUT “/1/comments/1/like" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-06 18:54:38 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#upvote_post_comment as JS
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>”1”, "id"=>”1”}
```

How do I get the voting to work via Javascript? So that the vote goes through, the vote count updates and the vote icon updates to voted.png instead of vote.png?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log says the request is formatted as JS.

```
Processing by CommentsController#upvote_post_comment as JS
```

Add `data: { type: :json }` to the `link_to` method to request a JSON format like so,

```
<%= link_to image_tag('vote.png'), like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, class: 'vote', remote: true, data: { type: :json } %>
```

This will tell the controller you want a JSON response not a Javascript response.

**Edit** - updates from the comments.

Update controller to use,

```
format.json { render json: { count: @comment.likes.size } }
```

Update JS to use,

```
.on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).html(data.count); });
```

Comment: That gives me the exact same problem

Comment: Change the 'ajax:error' function to `.on('ajax:error', function(e, xhr, status, error) { console.log(status); console.log(error); })` and check the browser console to see what gets printed out.

Comment: I get: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `liked_count' for #<Comment:0x00000106c6f050>):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in upvote_post_comment'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:56:in `upvote_post_comment'

Comment: Looks like the method `liked_count` doesn't exist for that comment. Try changing the `respond_to` json block to `format.json { render json: { count: @comment.likes.size } }`.

Comment: This time, I dont get an error at all, the vote count just does not update. This ran in the terminal: Processing by CommentsController#upvote_post_comment as JSON

Comment: Change the `ajax:success` to this `.on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).html(data.count); });`. Hopefully this should be the last fix :)

Comment: OMGG!!!! It worked!! :)) Well, kind of, so I had the vote icon, and the vote count which was zero, it made the vote icon disappear and and become the number 1, and kept the original comment count placeholder at zero. Can we continue this in the chat box thing?

Comment: I just have to get the number to update in the right place on the view! And get the image to update from vote.png to voted.png!

Comment: Great. I'd love to help more but it's 2:15 am (GMT) and I've got work tomorrow. I'll try and pick up any more questions tomorrow.

Comment: Ooooh!! Gotchya!! Is there a way I kind get the votes size to update in the right spot? Do you see where I have <a><%= "#{comment.votes.size}"%></a> in my view? Can I put something else there to tell the AJAX to put the new number there?

Comment: If that `a` tag is next to the link that was clicked, you could do `$(this).next().html(data.count)` or you could give the `a` tag a css class or id and do this `$('.item-class').html(data.count)` or `$('#item-id').html(data.count)`.

Comment: Should I put them inside script tags and right next to the a tag?